# How to count number of elements with AQL?

Tags: count, arangodb

I need to count elements that was in result of SQL query:
`db._query('FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == "127.0.0.1" return COUNT(v.guid) ')`

This request is return my a length of every GUID, but I need to get total number of GUIDs for example: 2.

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the result of the query as input for the `COUNT` function, and then `RETURN` this result.

You can replace the `RETURN` value of the actual query by `1` for performance reasons:

```
RETURN COUNT(FOR v IN visitors FILTER v.ip == "127.0.0.1" RETURN 1)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use `LENGTH` rather than `COUNT`.

Comment: `COUNT` is actually an alias of `LENGTH`, so you're invoking the same code path inside of the ArangoDB server. Whatever you changed in your query must have been more than swapping the both to make it work.

Comment: Mhh. Nope. Just changing that one word. If I use COUNT I get [ArangoError 1540: usage of unknown function 'COUNT()' (while parsing)]. Maybe the alias was introduced in a version newer than the one I use.

Comment: The currently supported versions don't show that behaviour. Maybe you should upgrade? Which version are you running? Maybe a github issue would be better to continue this.

Answer (score 3):

Version from 2022!

```
FOR m IN messages 
FILTER DATE_HOUR(m.date) == 3
COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO length
RETURN length
```

Comment: Great, at last they have this functionality. :)